# PHP change all classes on website during render

Tags: php, html

Short and simple question: I want to rename all classes during the page load to hide them a bit so I want to use generic ones instead. Is this even possible or do I need to rename all classes manually?

If there is a function in PHP how can I use this?

Comment: _I want to rename all classes during the page load to hide them a bit.._ Huh? Why? Edit: And why do you think that classes are hidden after renaming? They just will have new names

Comment: You could use ob_* functions and replace but seems like an xy problem, or just being lazy ;p

Comment: Just place all elements in a div and hide that on render?